# Having a Backbone Model id only unique among a collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Is it a good or a bad practice to have **a Backbone model where its id is only unique among a collection but not unique globally**? (because contextualized to that collection)

For instance I have a model `A` which contains `bs` a collection of model `B`.
The `B` collection belongs to the model `A`.
If I have `a1` and `a2` two instances of `A`, Can I use a `B` with `id=1` in `a1` and another `B` with `id=1` in `a2` ?

Maybe I don't see all the implication but it quite make sense, I just wanted to check with you before using it massively!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2 are separate collection you can definitely have id's that are unique to that collection.

Unless the 2 collections interact with each other which may  cause any collision in `ids`

Comment: This is what I think so far, i'm just wondering if there is some edge cases where this can break (Like if there is a way in backbone to globally retrieve a model by it's id)

Comment: You always access the model by id, for a specific collection. So if you want to get a `model with id 2` from `collection B` then you would do `B.get(2)`. But you can never get a model from all the collection globally

Comment: @gre.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is that they represent the same entity or not...if yes their id can be the same otherwise I wouldnt recommend that. If they are the same entities they should be the same reference to a single object.

You will always have an autogenerated unique identifier for all Backbone models, the `cid` attribute.

Comment: Why would you not recommend that? I'm interested by the reason behind.